# Is it correct to say "it's" after the subject?

Tags: grammar

I've seen many times sentences like this:

> The telephone it's blue.

Which, I find it redundant since **telephone** already implies "it", and "is" should be enough, but I've seen it so many times I needed to ask.

Comment: It's reasonably legitimate if you insert a comma.

Comment: With a comma, your sentence would be an example of *left dislocation*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax)

Comment: That is a typical French structure: L'état, c'est moi. There's a difference between written sentences and speech. How come that's not an obvious thing?

Comment: The vase is red. The candlesticks are red. The model ship is red. But the telephone – it's blue.

Comment: It's an example of left dislocation, like in *"**This little girl**, the dog bit **her**"*

Answer (score 1):

As pablopaul says, this is left dislocation, and emphasises the telephone. You would need the comma before "it's". This use would only occur in conversational cases and is not recommended in formal written English.

Answer (score 0):

More context here would be appreciated. As it stands without context, no, it does not work. If you're wanting to say that blue is its color, you would say that "the telephone is blue".

If somebody says "The telephone", but then wants to elaborate that it's blue (perhaps to differentiate it from other phones), then you can use an em dash or a semicolon. "The telephone — it's blue", or "The telephone; it's blue".

For other contexts, you could write "The telephone, which is blue, is over there", or "The telephone (the blue one) is over there". In that last example, those parentheses could be replaced with em dashes.

Comment: can we write "The telephone, it's blue"?